# Adding a comment from a specific user in a bugzilla extension

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I am writing a bugzilla extension which adds a comment to bugs when they are submitted using the `bug_end_of_create()` hook. Regardless of what I pass in the "who" parameter, the comment always appears to have been created by the user that submitted the bug. How do you set the user when creating a comment?

```
use Bugzilla::User;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

sub install_update_db {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;

}

sub bug_end_of_create {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    my $bug = $args->{'bug'};

    $bug->add_comment('[automated message]', {"who" => 'me@domain.com'});
}

__PACKAGE__->NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs for add_comment do not mention the "who" parameter.

However, there is `Bugzilla::Comment`, which has an author.

I would therefore think that the way of achieving what you want is to make a new `Bugzilla::Comment` with the bug id and author.

You should have the bug id available in the hook.
You will have to fetch the `Bugzilla::User` object for the author ( via the email, which you seem to have ).

I have not tested this.

Comment: I ended up solving my problem in an orthogonal way that did not require adding new comments, but I'll try this approach and report back.